# What kind of Ember Object is this error referring to with regards to a dynamic segment?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm learning Ember.js.

I have a template named `simpleSearchOption`, and the corresponding route and controller, `SimpleSearchOptionRoute` and `SimpleSearchOptionController`.

I had originally specified my model in the route as:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('simpleSearch')[params.simpleSearchOption_id];
},
```

I implemented the `setController` hook, and commented the line out since I'd be setting the model for the controller there, but when I do that, it breaks my application and Ember returns the following error:

```
Error: assertion failed: You used the dynamic segment simpleSearchOption_id 
in your route simpleSearchOption, but App.SimpleSearchOption did not exist 
and you did not override your route's `model` hook.
```

Is App.SimpleSearchOption referring to an Ember object that would be a model?

For the moment, I'm just going to reimplement the `model` hook, but I wanted to know the "Ember" way to handle this.

---

Edit:

Here is the relevant portion of my `Router`:

```
this.resource('simpleSearch', function() {
    this.resource('simpleSearchOption', {path: ':simpleSearchOption_id'});
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevent parts of your `Router` setup.

Comment: That is the relevant part.  What else should I include?  I'll include the `setupController` function, but I think it's irrelevant, since I'm asking specifically about the result of removing the `model` hook.

Comment: Not your `Route`, your `Router` setup.  Where you define your resources.

Comment: Oooohhh - sorry, I missed that 'r'.  I've added it in there.  I'm assuming that it's grabbing the `'simpleSearchOption_id'` and extrapolating `SimpleSearchOption` from it.  Is that supposed to be a model?  I'm not using ember-data, just as a side-note.